# Cannot query parquet file created by Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, parquet

Created a parquet file in Spark. Here is the code snippet

```
parquet_file_name = os.path.join(partition, os.path.basename(fileLocation) + ".parquet")

dfData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(addedColumns, schema)

dfData.save(parquet_file_name, "parquet", "append")
```

I can read the file contents in Spark.

```
In [1]:
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
parquetFile = sqlContext.parquetFile("/temp//browser/pub/browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet")
parquetFile.head(10)
​
Out[1]:
[Row(browserID=u'1', browserName=u'Lynx 2.7.1'),
 Row(browserID=u'2', browserName=u'Lynx 2.7'),
 Row(browserID=u'3', browserName=u'Lynx 2.6'),
 Row(browserID=u'4', browserName=u'Lynx 2.5'),
 Row(browserID=u'5', browserName=u'Lynx 2.4'),
 Row(browserID=u'6', browserName=u'Lynx (unknown version)'),
 Row(browserID=u'7', browserName=u'Lotus Notes 4.5'),
 Row(browserID=u'8', browserName=u'AOL 4.0'),
 Row(browserID=u'9', browserName=u'AOL 3.0'),
 Row(browserID=u'10', browserName=u'Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.0 beta 2')]
```

Created an Hive external table on parquet file using the following syntax

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE browser
(
fld1 string,
fld2 string,
FileName string,
LoadDate string,
Checksum string,
RecordId string
)
PARTITIONED BY (fname string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/temp/dims/browser';
```

Altered table to add the partition

```
ALTER TABLE browser ADD PARTITION (fname='browser.parquet')
LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/temp/dims/browser/browser.parquet';
```

Select * from table in Hue returns null for all rows and columns.

```
select * from browser;

browser.fld1    browser.fld2    browser.filename    browser.loaddate    browser.checksum    browser.recordid    browser.fname
0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet
4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet
5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet
6   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    browser.parquet/part-r-00001.parquet
```

Cloudera CDH 5.4.1

Spark 1.3.0

Hue 3.7.0

Any pointers how to fix this, if you need additional info needed I'll add.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you make an effort and explain better your problem?

Comment: Added more info, code and outputs. Thanks @AlbertoBonsanto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the hive schema you're using is different from your parquet file content, see :

```
Row(browserID=u'1', browserName=u'Lynx 2.7.1')
```

It doesn't look at all like the table definition.
You can look at the parquet schema in spark with something like:

```
val f = sqlContext.parquetFile( "your file")
f.schema.foreach( x => println(x.name, x.dataType))
```

and check how it differs from the hive one.

Also, just to make sure to cover all the basics, why don't you let spark create the hive table for you ?

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
yourDF.saveAsTable("yourtable")
```

Also, recent versions of hive support parquet natively so you should be able to just say "SAVE AS PARQUET" instead of specifying serde/inputformat/outputformat

Comment: You can use  f.printSchema() to get the schema

Comment: Thanks @Roberto Congiu. I have recreated the hive table with BrowserID and BrowserName columns, I can see the data.